# PowerShell expand (unpivot) all entries in a table column

Tags: powershell, outlook, powershell-3.0

I am trying to work out some Outlook Email stats using PowerShell. The one that is stopping me is working out the count of emails sent to each specific recipient. Outlook reports the "To" field as a single string containing a `;` separated list of recipients.

I want to expand that string so that, if an email was sent to 5 people, each person is counted.

For example, my code so far is:

```
# Create a link to Outlook
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
# Take a copy of the copy outbox (which is maintained by an Outlook rule)
$out = $namespace.Folders.Item('Local Copy').folders.item('Copy Outbox').items

# Group by who the email was sent to
$byTo = $out | group-object To -noelement |  sort Count -Descending | select Count, @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="To"}
```

Which returns something like:

```
Count To
----- --
   24 Fred Talkative
   11 A Person (Acme Corp); Jim Twobob (Customer Org)
    9 Someone Smith (Acme Corp); Jane Twobob (Customer Org)
```

Whereas, what I want to see is something like:

```
Count To
----- --
   24 Fred Talkative
   11 A Person (Acme Corp)
    1 Jim Twobob (Customer Org)
    9 Someone Smith (Acme Corp)
    1 Jane Twobob (Customer Org)
```

I've tried using the `split` function:

```
$expr = @{Expression={$_.To -split '; '};Label="ToSplit"}
$byTo | select Count, $expr | select Property * -ExpandProperty ToSplit
```

But this loses the count.

How can I get the output I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is sound, you're just doing things out of order. Try this:

```
$splitTo = $out | % {@($_.To -split '; ')}
$byTo = $splitTo | group-object $_ -noelement | sort Count -Descending | select Count, @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="To"}
```

Comment: Probably a sensible change. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The output is the same except that the `; ` has been removed when showing the `ToSplit` field.

Comment: It needs to expand the split expression but if I do that, I don't seem to be able to do a group-object any more - I just get a single entry.

Comment: Removed the expression bit and added an extra step. I think this works properly.

Comment: Yay! Clearly I've still a lot to learn about PowerShell. You're the man! A well earned accept from me. Many thanks. I just need to study it now to try and understand it. PowerShell often reminds me of working in [APL](http://www.computerhistory.org/atchm/the-apl-programming-language-source-code/) many years ago. :)